# Cant style any text. Cant target p tag or h tag

Tags: html, css

Im trying to target this h2 tag and this p tag in the div with the id="second"

For some reason it doesnt matter what i try i cant target any text i add to this html.

Im sure its something silly im missing but i cant find it no matter what.

Heres the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/odjfmv1g/1/

Also im sure theres a better way to format this fiv and p tag for future text so if you have ay siggestions please feel free to let me know or change in the fiddle.

```
    <div id="second">
    <h2 id="h2">What we do</h2>
    <p id="p2">Let us take your buisness to the next level</p>
    </div>

#h2{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
```

I also would like to place it in the center of page as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your css is not valid,

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5;  // missing )
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5;     // missing )
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

if you paste your css here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

it wold show you that you have error at lines 180, 181 and 182.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, since i cant use fill: white. what can i use to change the color of the svg. color:white does not work

Comment: is fill: white not working? I thought it was working... you can ignore that error, white is a valid color name. color: white is equivalent to color: #ffffff.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to style your html in div is

```
#second>h2{
//CSS CODE
}
```

This is because your h2 and p is in another div (container) not in the body directly. Or you might use class stlye like
Html:

```
<h2 class="myStyle">some word</h2>
```

Css:

```
.myStyle{
  //css code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't style those elements is because the `-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5;` and `-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5;` declarations in the `.btn2` selector are missing closing parentheses.

As far as better styling options and centering the text, I'll let someone more adept at CSS than I answer that.